# How to sync roles across Multisite?

Tags: multisite, user-roles, sync

How to synchronize roles on all sites of the Multisite Network if roles were changed on main site?

Answer (score 2):

There's an action hook in the [`set_role`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php#L799) function.

It's a matter of detecting if this is happening in the main site, and, if it does, get all blogs of the user and change all roles. More details in code comments.

```
add_action( 'set_user_role', 'sync_user_roles_wpse_91745', 10, 2 );

function sync_user_roles_wpse_91745( $user_id, $role )
{
    // is_multisite() used just as precaution, this code is meant to Multisite only
    if( !is_multisite() || !is_main_site() )
        return;

    // Initial data
    $blogs = get_blogs_of_user( $user_id );
    $original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

    // Remove main site from affected sites
    unset( $blogs[ $original_blog_id ] );

    // Iterate through blogs of user
    foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) 
    {
        // Work with another site
        switch_to_blog( $blog->userblog_id );

        // Grab all user info and update role as in main site
        $site_user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
        $site_user->set_role( $role );
    }

    // Back to original main site
    switch_to_blog( $original_blog_id );    
}
```

I didn't know that, but the user ID remains the same across the network, in the tables `wp_users` and `wp_{$site_id}_users`.

Comment: Is this code still valid? Does this creates an infinite loop?